# Is it possible to cat an ELF file and pipe it into objdump

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to `cat` an ELF file and pipe the output to `objdump` in a bash shell but after reading the `objdump` man page it does not look like there is an option to use STDIN in place of a file.  Is there an alternate way of achieving this?

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
    cat my_elf_file | objdump -h -
```

Comment: Looks like objdump doesn't support that. You'll need to create a temporary file.

Comment: PS: I guess that's because `objdump` needs random access to the file meaning it can address any portion of the file at any time. When you pipe stdin to it, objdump would only be able to read it once.

Comment: After looking at `objdump` related source code, I suspect that @hek2mgl is correct.